# Generating parameterized F# quotations

Tags: f#, quotations

Let's say we have a simple F# quotation:

```
type Pet = {  Name : string }
let exprNonGeneric = <@@ System.Func(fun (x : Pet) -> x.Name) @@>
```

The resulting quotation is like:

```
val exprNonGeneri : Expr =
  NewDelegate (System.Func`2[[FSI_0152+Pet, FSI-ASSEMBLY, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]],
             x, PropertyGet (Some (x), System.String Name, []))
```

Now I want to generalize it, so I instead of type "Pet" and property "Name" I could use an arbitrary type and method/property defined on it. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
let exprGeneric<'T, 'R> f = <@@ System.Func<'T, 'R>( %f ) @@>
let exprSpecialized = exprGeneric<Pet, string> <@ (fun (x : Pet) -> x.Name) @>
```

The resulting expression is now different:

```
val exprSpecialized : Expr =
  NewDelegate (System.Func`2[[FSI_0152+Pet, FSI-ASSEMBLY, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]],
             delegateArg,
             Application (Lambda (x,
                                  PropertyGet (Some (x), System.String Name, [])),
                          delegateArg))
```

As you can see, the difference between the first and the second expression is that in first case the top level NewDelegate expression contains PropertyGet, while the second expression wraps PropertyGet in a Application/Lambda expression. And when I pass this expression to an external code it does not expect such expression structure and fails.

So I need some way to build a generalized version of quotation, so when it gets specialized, the resulting quotation is an exact match of <@@ System.Func(fun (x : Pet) -> x.Name) @@>. Is this possible? Or it there only choice to manually apply pattern matching to a generated quotation and transform it to what I need?

**UPDATE**. As a workaround I implemented the following adapter:

```
let convertExpr (expr : Expr) =
    match expr with
    | NewDelegate(t, darg, appl) ->
        match (darg, appl) with
        | (delegateArg, appl) ->
            match appl with 
            | Application(l, ldarg) ->
                match (l, ldarg) with
                | (Lambda(x, f), delegateArg) ->
                    Expr.NewDelegate(t, [x], f)
                | _ -> expr
            | _ -> expr
    | _ -> expr
```

It does the job - I can now convert expression from 1st to 2nd form. But I am interested in finding out if this can be achieved in a simple way, without traversing expression trees.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it will be possible to do this; in the second case, you are plugging in the expression `<@ (fun (x : Pet) -> x.Name) @>`, which is represented using a `Lambda` node, into the hole in the other expression.  The compiler does not simplify expressions during this plugging process, so the `Lambda` node won't be removed no matter what you do.

However your pattern matching workaround can be greatly simplified:

```
let convertExpr = function
| NewDelegate(t, [darg], Application(Lambda(x,f), Var(arg))) 
    when darg = arg -> Expr.NewDelegate(t, [x], f)
| expr -> expr
```

In fact, your more complicated version is incorrect.  This is because the `delegateArg` in your innermost pattern is not matching against the value of the previously bound `delegateArg` identifier from the outer pattern; it is a new, freshly bound identifier which also happens to be called `delegateArg`.  In fact, the outer `delegateArg` identifier has type `Var list` while the inner one has type `Expr`!  However, given the limited range of expression forms generated by the compiler your broken version may not be problematic in practice.

**EDIT**

Regarding your followup questions, if I understand you correctly it may not be possible to achieve what you want.  Unlike C#, where `x => x + 1` could be interpreted as having a type of either `Func<int,int>` or `Expression<Func<int,int>>`, in F# `fun x -> x + 1` is always of type `int->int`.  If you want to get a value of type `Expr<int->int>` then you generally need to use the quotation operator `(<@ @>)`.

There is one alternative that may be of use, however.  You can use the `[<ReflectedDefinition>]` attribute on let bound functions to make their quotations available as well.  Here's an example:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.ExprShape
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.Patterns
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.DerivedPatterns

let rec exprMap (|P|_|) = function
| P(e) -> e
| ShapeVar(v) -> Expr.Var v
| ShapeLambda(v,e) -> Expr.Lambda(v, exprMap (|P|_|) e)
| ShapeCombination(o,l) -> RebuildShapeCombination(o, l |> List.map (exprMap (|P|_|)))


let replaceDefn = function
| Call(None,MethodWithReflectedDefinition(e),args) 
    -> Some(Expr.Applications(e, [args]))
| _ -> None


(* plugs all definitions into an expression *)
let plugDefs e = exprMap replaceDefn e

[<ReflectedDefinition>]
let f x = x + 1

(* inlines f into the quotation since it uses the [<ReflectedDefinition>] attribute *)
let example = plugDefs <@ fun y z -> (f y) - (f 2) @>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and a great suggestion. I am however still stuck with related issue: is it possible at all to plug a simple F# delegate (e.g. fun x -> x.Name) into a generic quotation that is independent of the actual type, like the quotation #2 above. This is similar to what mocking frameworks do: they define some expressions without knowing concrete interfaces and inject concrete types. I don't seem to be able to achieve this in F#.

Comment: @Vagif - I'm not sure I understand your question.  Could you go into a bit more detail on what you're trying to do?

Comment: I need to send interop between F# and C#. C# expects LINQ expression of a certain kind. I can write it in F# in hard-coded manner, but I want to build a generic F# wrapper for this. This wrapper should be able to take as input lambdas like "fun x -> x.Name" and convert them into quotations. I am beginning to suspect this is not possible in general case.

Comment: @Vagif - I've added some more thoughts in an edit.  Unfortunately, depending on exactly what you're trying to do, it may not possible.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent comments. Things became clearer but not brighter :-( From what you're saying it looks I must use ReflectedDefinition attribute if I want expressions to be inlined into quotations, but then they won't be arbitrary because of this attribute.

Thanks again!